# Why "symbol@GOT" is not permitted on pie binary?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, position-independent-code, got

Here is sample assembly file, `test.s`

```
.global main  
main:  
 mov __progname@GOT, %eax         // failed to compile
 mov __progname@GOT(%ebx), %eax   //succeed to compile
```

I tried compiling it with `-pie` flag, but failed.

```
$ gcc -pie -o test test.s
osboxes@osboxes:/mnt/hgfs/VM_Shared/Reassemblabla/src$ gcc -pie -o test test.s
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPGMLlH.o: direct GOT relocation R_386_GOT32X against `__progname' without base register can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Error said, In pie binary, access to `GOT` entry is only available using base register.

***Question.***
I don't know why compiler is complaining like above.
More specifically, why `__progname@GOT` addressing is not permitted on pie binary?

***My opinion.***
Loader knows the address of `__progname@GOT` in loading time of pie binary.

So, loader can simply write this address at location of `__progname@GOT` in loading time.
That's what loader can do.

So I cannot understand why compiler insist on register-relative accessing like
`mov __progname@GOT(%ebx), %eax`.

Comment: Loader does not usually write into code section as that would break sharing across processes which is important for libraries. It's not particularly useful for executables but since PIE is built on top of the same functionality it is not allowed.

Comment: @Jester But... loader write into code section when we use direct memory access. For example, When we use instruction like `mov MY_SYMBOL, %eax` and compile it into pie binary, address of `MY_SYMBOL` is not fixed until loading time. In this case, loader write address of `MY_SYMBOL` into <.text> section at loading time.

Comment: Yeah, technically it would be possible but the whole point of a GOT is to avoid relocations in code. If you can live with relocations you don't need a GOT and can just use the simple relocation you showed.

Comment: @Jester Oh It make sence. Yes, you are right. We use GOT to avoid relocation in code, and accessing GOT section with relocaion is weird...like contradicting itself. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Interesting question. This [source](https://github.com/bsdjhb/gdb/blob/master/bfd/elf32-i386.c#L2561) has a comment about the GOT address being unknown for PICs. I don't know why that should be the case for a shared library, the local GOT is known. Maybe they are talking about the GOT of another module? Also `lea` is allowed (documented in the ABI). Finally, it seems the description of the algorithm is deceiving, the *end* of the `.got` section is subtracted. I can't think of any reason for this, right now.

Answer (score 1):

PIE is supposed to use pc-relative addressing; ia32 is crap at this, so you need to do something like:

```
    call thunk
    add  $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE__, %eax
    mov  __progname@GOT(%eax), %eax
    ret
thunk:
    mov (%esp), %eax
    ret
```

Notice offset from this program address to the _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE__ is computed to reference GOT.  Thus the program can be *loaded* (as opposed to linked or located) at any address, and will find the GOT, and all variables, because the relative offset is the same.
For reference, the amd64 version of the above is something like:

```
mov    __progname(%rip), %rax
ret
```

Notice that both of these keep the text ‘pure’....